# Take first element from dynamic JsonConvert.DeserializeObject array

Tags: c#, json

I have json string output like that:

string apiResult =

```
{
   "error":[],
   "result":{
      "RARAGA":{
         "a":["4","1","1.1"],
         "b":["4","1","2"],
         "c":["1","2"],
         "v":["4","4"],
         "p":["5","2"],
         "t":[1],
         "l":["3","4"],
         "h":["5","7"],
         "o":"8"
      }
   }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to convert it with Newtonsoft.Json:

```
dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(apiResult);
```

to only take this result of "RARAGA" property as an object so I can take its values a/b/c etc. I just need to take it's values like:

```
result.result.RARAGA.a[0]
```

Point is this string **"RARAGA" is always random**

Comment: In the sample you've provided `RARAGA` is not an element of Array it's a property. Check the sample JSON

Comment: Right my bad. Anyway I cannot access to it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you don't know what is the name of property (or want to iterate all properties) you can use `JObject`

```
JObject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(apiResult);
dynamic res = result["result"].First().First;
```

res will contains a value of first object as a dynamic variable

Comment: Yes, big thanks. I was almost on it (found out to use JObject) but your 2 lines are looking much much better. Big thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you use http://json2csharp.com/# then below should be the model you should deserialize your json string to

```
public class RARAGA
{
    public List<string> a { get; set; }
    public List<string> b { get; set; }
    public List<string> c { get; set; }
    public List<string> v { get; set; }
    public List<string> p { get; set; }
    public List<int> t { get; set; }
    public List<string> l { get; set; }
    public List<string> h { get; set; }
    public string o { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public RARAGA RARAGA { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<object> error { get; set; }
    public Result result { get; set; }
}
```

So your deserialization would become

```
RootObject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(apiResult);
```

Then you can access it like

```
result.result.RARAGA.a[0]
```

Comment: Usually I would go this way but here "RARAGA" is always a random different string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
result.result[0]["a"][0]
```

use **result[0]** instead **result.RARAGA**

Comment: Unfortunately not working `Accessed JObject values with invalid key value: 0. Object property name expected.`

Answer (score 0):

Use the class `RARAGA` from Rahul's answer and convert the `JToken` (like ASpirin's answer):

```
public class RARAGA
{
    public List<string> a { get; set; }
    public List<string> b { get; set; }
    public List<string> c { get; set; }
    public List<string> v { get; set; }
    public List<string> p { get; set; }
    public List<int> t { get; set; }
    public List<string> l { get; set; }
    public List<string> h { get; set; }
    public string o { get; set; }
}

JObject loObject = JObject.Parse(apiResult);
RARAGA loRARAGA = loObject["result"].First.First.ToObject<RARAGA>();
Console.WriteLine(loRARAGA.a[0]);
```